# Capturing printer data

Tags: printers

Is there a way to capture what is printed by public printer?
Or is it possible to control the printer (shutting it off or printing remotely)?

Comment: You could rephrase the question as: is it possible to capture network traffic, and is it possible to hack computers. Yes, yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to capture what is printed by public printer?

Sure. There are some mitigations for various threats (like TLS on the connection against MITM), but asked like that it can be clearly answered with "Yes".

> printing remotely

is possible too, the same way.

> shutting it off

Sure. If the printer can be shut off remotely at all, then an attacker can do it too.